# SwiftUI: How to change placeholder font of TextField?

Tags: swiftui

```
TextField(Text("Placeholder").font(.custom("font-name", size: 22)), $text)
```

How to change placeholder font of TextField?
Maybe to use some attributed string.
I have tried to wrap it as a `Text` but no luck, got next error:

> Initializer 'init(_:text:onEditingChanged:onCommit:)' requires that
> 'Text' conform to 'StringProtocol'

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Simply you can Use this:

```
TextField("", text: $text, prompt: Text("Placeholder").font(.custom("font-name", size: 22)))
```

**2.** You may Use your custom placeholder :

Make your placeholder:

```
 public struct PlaceholderStyle: ViewModifier {
    var showPlaceHolder: Bool
    var placeholder: String

    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if showPlaceHolder {
                Text(placeholder)
                .padding(.horizontal, 15)
            }
            content
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .padding(5.0)            
        }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
    TextField("", text: $data)
.modifier(PlaceholderStyle(showPlaceHolder: data.isEmpty,
                           placeholder: "My Placeholder"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with different constructor, using `prompt`, like

```
TextField("", text: $text, prompt: Text("Placeholder").font(.custom("font-name", size: 22)))

// or 

TextField(text: $text, prompt: Text("Placeholder").font(.custom("font-name", size: 22))) {
   Text("Label here or empty view")
}
```

Comment: still does not change the color of the placeholder for me